# XML and WordPress assistance

Tags: xml, wordpress

My developer set up a datastream connection to an outside source that is pulling product into my WordPress website. I need to use code similar to the code below to show the categories. There is also code for the search box.

How do I insert this code into a WordPress page so that it shows the categories?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLDataStreamRequest>
<Ver>3.2</Ver>
<Auth>
<AcctID>XXXXXX</AcctID>
<LoginID>XXXXXX</LoginID>
<Password>XXXXXXXXXXXX</Password>
</Auth>
<CategoryList>
<GetList>1</GetList>
<Sort>NAME</Sort>
</CategoryList>
</XMLDataStreamRequest>
```

Comment: Do you want this content show up on a site or you want to use the wordpress api to fetch only a xml?

Comment: I want the content to show. The results to show.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as far as I understand you want you to create one where the list is displayed.

#### 1

Create a site in the backend called "categorylist"

#### 2

you create a file in your theme called `page-categorylist.php`

*Please try now that when you open the categorylist page that if it's just white. if it's not you made a mistake.*

#### 3

put this in the file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');

function getCats() {
$categories = get_categories();
$src .= "<XMLDataStreamRequest><Ver>3.2</Ver><Auth><AcctID>XXXXXX</AcctID><LoginID>XXXXXX</LoginID><Password>XXXXXXXXXXXX</Password></Auth><CategoryList>"
foreach($categories as $category) {
              src .= "<GetList>" . $category->term_id . "</GetList><Sort>" . $category->name ."</Sort>";
}
$src .= "</CategoryList></XMLDataStreamRequest>"

    return $src;

}

echo getCats();
```

Comment: Create a "site" on the backend?
I use Oxygen Builder to build the custom pages.
I tried inserting your code into a codeblock in the page and I'm getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in /home/jtampk6srtjs/public_html/wp-content/plugins/oxygen/component-framework/components/classes/code-block.class.php(115) : eval()'d code on line 7

This is line 7: foreach($categories as $category) {